# Почему Djnago не видит функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть такая функция:

```
def getNearestNotes(request, longitude, latitude):
if request.method == 'GET':
    c = connection.cursor()
    r = None
    try:
        c.callproc('GetAllNotes', (float(longitude), float(latitude)))
        r = c.fetchall()
    finally:
        c.close()
    return HttpResponse(str(r))
else:
    return HttpResponse('needGetMethod')
```

Она должна вызвать такую функцию в postgresql базе:

```
create function "GetAllNotes"(long numeric, lat numeric)
      returns TABLE
      (
        UserId   integer,
        UserName character varying,
        NoteName character varying,
        NoteLong double precision,
        NoteLat  double precision
      )
      language plpgsql
      as
      $$
      BEGIN
      RETURN query (SELECT Notes."UserId", Users."Name", Notes."Name", 
      Notes."Longitude", Notes."Latitude"
            FROM Notes
                   INNER JOIN Users ON Notes."UserId" = Users."Id"
            WHERE (point(long, lat) <@> point(Notes."Longitude", 
      Notes."Latitude") <= 0.124274));
      END
      $$;
      alter function "GetAllNotes"(numeric, numeric) owner to postgres;
```

"Но при вызове этой функции django выдает ошибку - 
ОШИБКА:  функция getallnotes(numeric, numeric) не существует
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM GetAllNotes(28.0,23.0)
HINT:  Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов."
База подключена.

Comment: А ты точно функцию добавил?. Попробуй выполнить сырой sql `c.execute("SELECT * FROM GetAllNotes(28.0,23.0)")`. Если будет ошибка то проблема не в django а в базе. Там реально нет функции.

Comment: @Andru выдает ошибку. Но если я сделаю так:

`c.execute("SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type='FUNCTION' AND specific_schema='public'")
      r = c.fetchone()`
, то функция 'GetAllNotes' будет в списке

Comment: @Andru Хотя, когда django выдает ошибку, то он пишет функция getallnotes(numeric, numeric)... в нижем регистре. Может в этом проблема? Хотя в коде я пишу как нужно.

Comment: Важно то что в коде написано. Попробуй  в консоли psql вызвать функцию. Подключись с тем же логином и паролем что и в джанго указал.

Comment: @Andru из консоли не могу, так как возникает ошибка 'ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"'. На WIN1252 кодировка в БД не меняется.

Comment: А в какой момент возникает ошибка?

Comment: @Andru странно. Сейчас не могу вызвать эту ошибку. Раньше возникала, когда вводил `psql -U postgres -d dbname -c 'select * from GetAllNotes(27.0, 27.0)', 
а сейчас получаю - ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'select"
LINE 1: select
А до ошибки, после команды вот такое выводится:

psql: warning: extra command-line argument "*" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "from" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "GetAllNotes(27.0," ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "27.0)'" ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так - `c.callproc('"GetAllNotes"', (float(longitude), float(latitude)))` работает.

Comment: Видимо, при создании функции не нужно было ставить эти самые `"кавычки"`— они стали частью имени функции. Попробуйте лучше пересоздать функцию без кавычек

Comment: @andreymal я их не ставил. Это dataGrip делает. Но да, если их удалить из функции, то и в djnago они не нужны.

Comment: @andreymal постгрес использует двойные кавычки для именования таблиц, схем и функций. В коменте написано что функция сохранилась без кавычек. Тут что-то поинтересней

Comment: @eri то-есть правильно с кавычками? Тогда почему когда я создал дополнения с помощью CREATE EXTENSION, названия созданных функций без кавычки записаны?

Comment: кавычки правильны, но не обязательны. https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/8d20c685e19284e4bcf404e4aac7a33d